# Read Atom Feed by XPATH in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, atom-feed

The problem is that the code couldn't read Atom feed xml format like [this URL](http://wintermute.com.au/bits.atom).

I have no idea what is wrong in the code, but the code doesn't has any issue with RSS version 2.0 and every thing are good

There is C# code simple I have used to read rss feed and atom

if have any solution I will appreciate

```
XmlDocumentxmlDoc=newXmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("http://wintermute.com.au/bits.atom");
XmlNodeListitemNodes=xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//feed/entry");
foreach(XmlNodeitemNodeinitemNodes)
{
  //TitleTag
  if(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("title")!=null)
  {
    titletag=itemNode.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
  }
  else
  {
    titletag="Notitlefound";
  }
  //PubDateTag
  if(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("published")!=null)
  {
    pubDatetag=itemNode.SelectSingleNode("published").InnerText;
  }
  else
  {
    pubDatetag="Nopublishedfound";
  }
  //LinkTag
  if(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("link")!=null)
  {
    linktag=itemNode.SelectSingleNode("link").InnerText;
  }
  else
  {
    linktag="NopubDatefound";
  }
  //Logo,Image
  if(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("logo")!=null)
  {
    imgtag=itemNode.SelectSingleNode("logo").InnerText;
  }
  if(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("image")!=null)
  {
    imgtag=itemNode.SelectSingleNode("image").InnerText;
  }
  else
  {
    imgtag="NoImagefound";
  }
  //summaryTag
  if(itemNode.SelectSingleNode("summary")!=null)
  {
    destag=itemNode.SelectSingleNode("summary").InnerText;
  }
  else
  {
    destag="Nosummaryfound";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `feed` tag is in a namespace and defines the default namespace for the document. You need to set up a [NameSpaceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) and use that one in `SelectSingleNode()`.

Something like

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(source);
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("f", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var something= doc.SelectSingleNode("//f:feed/f:entry", nsmgr);
```

A problem is that the feed is invalid XML. The embedded IFrame in line 188 (at the time of writing) uses HTML syntax which is invalid in XML.

```
<iframe [...] allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In XML, there cannot be an attribute `allowfullscreen` without a value. IMHO the website should use `<![CDATA[...]]>` to insert the HTML.